# User Interaction in JSP

Tags: jsp

I cannot get user input values from applet or java web start that is embedded in java server pages (jsp).

Is there any other way to provide user interactivity while I can get user inputs values so that I can use it to do some calculations and processing?

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

//JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
JLabel myPanels[];
int counter = 0;
int temp = 0;
int correctPair =0 ;
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
public GUI(){

    answers.add("2");
    answers.add("7");
    answers.add("9");
    answers.add("10");
    answers.add("11");
    answers.add("14");

  //  super("Grid");

    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    addMouseListener(this);

    myPanels = new JLabel[16];

    for (int x = 0;x<myPanels.length;x++){

        myPanels[x]=new JLabel("");
        myPanels[x].setOpaque(true);
        myPanels[x].setBackground(Color.white);
        myPanels[x].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        myPanels[x].addMouseListener(this); // <-- add same listener to each grid

    }
    myPanels[2].setText("A");
    myPanels[14].setText("B");

    for (int x = 0;x<myPanels.length;x++){

        myPanels[x].setName(x+"");

    }

    List<Integer> rolls = Arrays.asList(0,1,4,5,8,9,12,13);

    Collections.shuffle(rolls);
    myPanels[rolls.get(0)].setBackground(Color.green);
    myPanels[rolls.get(1)].setBackground(Color.green);



    List<Integer> rolls_left = Arrays.asList(2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15);

    Collections.shuffle(rolls);
    myPanels[rolls_left.get(0)].setBackground(Color.green);








 //Add all the squares (JLabels)
    for (int x = 0;x<myPanels.length;x++)
    add(myPanels[x]);
}


 public static void main(String arg[]) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.setSize(200,200);
    gui.setResizable(false);
    gui.setVisible(true);




  }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    float[] dash1 = { 2f, 0f, 2f };

       BasicStroke bs1 = new BasicStroke(1, 
        BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, 
        BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 
        1.0f, 
        dash1,
        2f);
    g2d.setStroke(bs1);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.drawLine(101, 0,101 , 200);

  }

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel clickedPanel = (JLabel) e.getSource();

    //Toggle colours    
    if (clickedPanel.getBackground()==Color.white)
    {
      counter++;
      clickedPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
      System.out.println("Box " + clickedPanel.getName() + " selected.");
      System.out.println("Counter:" + counter);
    }
    else if (clickedPanel.getBackground()==Color.green)
    {

    }
    else 
    {
        counter--;
        clickedPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        System.out.println("Box " + clickedPanel.getName() + " unselected.");

        System.out.println("Counter:" + counter);

    }
    System.out.println(clickedPanel.getLocation());
    System.out.println(clickedPanel.getName());


    System.out.println(clickedPanel.getBackground());

    for (int x = 0;x<myPanels.length;x++){

        if(myPanels[x].getBackground().getBlue() == 0 &&        myPanels[x].getBackground().getGreen() == 0)
        {
        System.out.println("Box "+ myPanels[x].getName() + " selected for the answer.");
        }

        if(myPanels[x].getBackground().getBlue() == 0 && myPanels[x].getBackground().getGreen() == 255)
        {
        System.out.println("Box "+ myPanels[x].getName() + " is the initial question box coloured.");
        }

    }



    for(int i=0; i< answers.size(); i++)
    {           
        temp =i;

        if(answers.get(i).equals("0") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("3"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("1") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("2"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("4") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("7"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("5") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("6"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("8") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("11"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("9") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("10"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("12") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("15"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else if (answers.get(i).equals("13") && answers.get(temp+1).equals("14"))
        {
            correctPair++;

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

  System.out.println("pairs: " + correctPair);        

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



 }
```

Above is my JFrame code where i can get user mouse clicked input in whatever box they clicked on.

I want to embed this in jsp so i have found out that embedding can be done using Java Web Start or applet. But i cant get the user input to do some logic processing.

So is there any other way to embed and get the input values as I am currently doing a project in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

> About the other way to provide user interactivity while I can get user input 
>   values so that I can use it to do some calculations and processing ::

You may use MVC (Model, view, Controller) approach to accomplish it.

- Here the view is the JSP page that will take user data using a form
  and send it to the controller.
- A servlet or the controller will be there in the server to retrieve
  it and send it to a simple model or a plain old java class where you
  can make your calculations.
- Then the servlet will retrieve the calculated data from the model and
  after that the servlet can dispatch the view to another JSP page to
  show the calculated data to the user.

Benefits::

This way your presentation is separated from the actual codes that performs the calculations. Hence web development becomes easier.

There are numerous tutorials online about MVC. Try them if you want to create professional web apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what i have now is swing components where user will need to use the mouse event to click to select their choices. So i have a JFrame now. I can convert it to applet but i will not be able to get the user choices and calculate the results in jsp.

Comment: @gonggong Please edit your question a bit and add the comments that you put here to the question. This may help you find your answer and still, I would say, keep the calculation out of the presentation or JSP. Perform that calculation in a plain java class and call the java class from the JSP to let the calculated data appear in the view/JSP. And if possible, then the code too. Stackoverflow specifications also require that you be clear about your question.

Comment: And another information. Swing apps are dead now. Javafx is a nice and easier framework to accomplish your task of event handling. You don't need to right codes for your UI components here and the code for GUI gets separated from java in a fxml file.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.. i meant calculations in the java servlet..yeah i will post some of my Jframe codes in a while to have a better understanding what i am trying to do.